# What is the best way to get pictures on your contacts with ICS (Galaxy Nexus)?

Tags: contacts, sync, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Before I bought my Galaxy Nexus I had a HTC Hero. HTC synced the pictures from Facebook to my contacts. This happened on the phone so when i activated my new Galaxy Nexus and synced it my contacts had no pictures. My question is what is the best way to add pictures to my contacts? I'd hate to go and do the manual labor and add a picture to each contact. Ideally Facebook would just transfer the pictures but they don't seem to want to do that. The solution dose not have to be with facebook at all but that is where most of my contacts have pictures.

Comment: "Best" is subjective. Better to just describe the problem you're trying to solve. (Please read the [FAQ].)

Answer (score 6):

The official facebook app will add pictures to your contacts if you set it to sync your contacts.

[image]

Looks like @Dunhamzzz got the SyncMyPix part in before me, I did not get a message that said that there had been a new answer, though.

I don't like that the facebook app removes all the data that it adds to your contacts if you remove the application. To counter the facebook issue, I use an app called [SyncMyPix](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nloko.android.syncmypix&hl=en) that can pull your facebook contacts and put the image on your contact on your device. The nice thing about SyncMyPix, if it doesn't match a contact, it lets you go through them at the end and say "Sync this Facebook Contact with this Android Contact", and it remembers that mapping so the next time you sync, they are "connected"

Comment: there must have been seconds in it! Have a +1

Comment: I cant seem to find this in the app? Where do you press to get this screen?

Comment: The app Home Screen, Menu -> Settings -> Sync Settings

Comment: Personally I like the idea of using a real FB client that can actually be used for FB as well, such as the official app, or Friendcaster [Pro], as opposed to a whole nother app just to sync the pictures and not give any other functionality. But that's personal preference.

Comment: syncMyPix was created before the facebook app did any syncing. I don't use facebook, I just "have one" because everyone I know has one. For a while I did not even have the FB app installed, and just used SMP.

Answer (score 2):

[HaxSync](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mots.haxsync&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5tb3RzLmhheHN5bmMiXQ..) will sync Facebook (high res) photos to your ICS device.

Answer (score 1):

Use SyncMyPix ([AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/syncmypix/com.nloko.android.syncmypix)|[Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nloko.android.syncmypix&hl=en)), it links up contacts with your Facebook friends based on names and downloads their profile picture for your contact picture. It might take a few tweaks for incomplete/weird names the first time round but should only take a few minutes.

You can set it to run routinely to keep them up to date too!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, full Facebook integration with pictures with the native app hasn't yet come to ICS. For you to get that kind of integration would need you to hack the contacts source code and add it. Additionally, even if they did come, I would guess that the app pull smaller low-res pics designed for 2.3 or lower as ICS uses full screen contact tiles

Instead, your best bet is to use the app [Friendcaster](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.senab.blueNotifyFree&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInVrLmNvLnNlbmFiLmJsdWVOb3RpZnlGcmVlIl0.). It is a fully featured Facebook application that also has ICS support, Facebook integration with contacts and the ability to download high resolution pictures. It works perfectly on my phone running ICS 4.0.3